# Why HiddenFor get null value in post action method in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view in whicn whenever i post the form, hiddenfor gets null value. When i add new one it gets null value but when i edit, it works fine.
I check the error by using this code.

```
var errors = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
    .ToArray();
```

Error says the id field is required.
I am using `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)`
the form is ajax.beginform
What is the problem?

EDIT:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ProductPartial(int Id = -1)
        {
            var ProductService = new ProductService();

            var Product = new Product();
            bool editMode = ProductId > 0;

            if (editMode)
            {
                var ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(ProductId);
                var entity = ProductService.GetByProductId(null, ProductId);
                Product.Id = entity.ProductId;
                Product.ProductName = entity.ProductName;

            }

            return PartialView(Product);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ProductPartial(Product Product)
        {
           //Product id gets null
           //Perfome some action


            return Json(returnData);
        }
Product class
 public abstract class ProductBase
{
    public virtual int Id{set;get}
    public virtual string Name {set;get}

}

public class Product : ProductBase
{}
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking. What is the type of property `Id`? What validation attributes have you applied to it?

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to debug your problem. Please take a look at the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to create a good question.

Comment: I have not applied any validation attribute and its type is int

Comment: then why it gets null

Comment: What do you mean _When i add new one_? You need to show your code

Comment: I have same form to edit and add new product

Comment: Please post the code of your Action methods. The one that returns the view and the one that is called when posting the form.

Comment: Great. Now the Product class definition please. :-) Just the members, not the methods.

Comment: Edit the product class

Comment: Can you check in Debug what value you are getting of parameter Id in Add New One because if that value shows(eg) then you will get null value?

Comment: yes i debugged. Id get 0 and name get the correct value. It should be 0.But modelstate.isvalid says the field id is requireed.But i did not put any validation on id field. It is a hidden field.

Comment: If you are getting that error, it means your posting back a `null` value. Do your have any scripts that are changing the value? Look at the html your generating - the hidden input should have `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" />`

Answer (score -2):

**This works:**

```
 // Controller
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(BitcoinTransactionViewModel **RedeemTransaction**)
    {
    }

    // View
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "DepositDetails", FormMethod.Post, new { **RedeemTransaction** = Model }))
    {

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Token);
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Transaction.TransactionId);
    .
    .
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question